# How to parse column with two types of date format in Talend

Tags: java, etl, talend, date

I have `.csv` file which has column called `created_ts`, and contains date values. However, date is written in two formats:

- 2016-12-07 14:12:58.727746+01 (`yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSX`)
- 2008-10-25 18:22:32+02 (`yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssX`)

So my problem is how to read data from `.csv` file without getting error "Unparseable date: 2008-10-25 18:22:32+02"

Here's the picture showing how I put date format, but for `created_ts` column I have date written in two different formats, so if I put first one, I get "Unparseable date: xxxxxx" error, and same error if I put second format....

[image]

Comment: I have downvoted this question because you are asking us about a bug without showing us code.  Without concrete code, we can only guess what the problem might be, which is not useful to you or future readers.  If you can [edit] your question to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem, this downvote may be retracted.

Comment: There is nothing to program. This is Talend Studio program, the problem is that I have column with two different date formats. In Talend Studio, if I have column containing dates, I woul set type of column Date and Date Pattern for the format and that is if entire column contains dates in single format (ex: `yyyy-MM-dd`). But this column in .csv contains dates in two different formats, and I do not know how to specify Talend to first try parse using one format and if that fails to try to parse using another format....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your dates can be of different formats, you need to read your column as a String type in your `tFileInputDelimited`, then inside a `tMap`, check the date type (a simple way to check it is by testing its length) and parse it using the correct date format:

```
tFileInputDelimited -- tMap -- output
```

In a tMap expression, you can have something like this :

```
row.created_ts.length() == 22 ? TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssX", row.created_ts) : TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSX", row.created_ts)
```